# AWS AppSync cannot access Aurora Serverless Postgres Cluster via VTL resolvers anymore

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-appsync, aws-rds-data-service

It seems like there was some kind of breaking change and now AWS AppSync cannot access Aurora Serverless Postgres Cluster via VTL resolvers anymore.

Following even the simplest examples like this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-rds-resolvers.html always results in

```
"error": {
            "message": "RDSHttp:{\"message\":\"This API is deprecated and not available. Use ExecuteStatement API instead\"}",
            "type": "400 Bad Request"
        },
```

I've tried manually (like the tutorial above) and with the CDK in `us-east-1` - I always get this error now, even in projects that worked before.

Has anybody come across this error and know how to fix it?

Comment: related github opened issue - https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/12735